# Not able to get the call status from quickblox

Tags: android, call, quickblox

I have integrated calling in my app with quickblox sdk but I am  not able to retrieve the status when I am trying to call a  user and that user is busy on another call. Anyone knows, please drop the comments!!

Comment: it would be helpful for all of us to answer if you share piece of code you have used where you are fetching status or how you making a call

Comment: I have used the sample code provided by quickblox sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a case when the opponent is busy on another call, use this callback:

```
/**
 * Called in case when opponent has rejected you call
 */
void onCallRejectByUser(QBRTCSession session, Integer userID, Map<String, String> userInfo);
```

What happens in this case is that the opponent receives a new session when the initiator is calling, so he will reject it if busy on another call.

You can check the full list of callbacks to track session status [here](https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Track_session_states_via_QBRTCClientSessionCallbacks_interface).